# Electron-vue: 'compute:' does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I tried to implement a simple sample using [element-ui](http://element-cn.eleme.io/#/en-US).
There are two 'switches' () each one has the value for active state: 2 and 1. The switches' values are displayed in `<p>{{sw1}}</p>` and `<p>{{sw2}}<>/p>` like this.

[image: The image of sample app]

Here is the component source 'Sample.vue':

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <el-switch v-model="sw1" active-value=2 inactive-value=0></el-switch>
    <p>{{sw1}}</p>
    <el-switch v-model="sw2" active-value=1 inactive-value=0></el-switch>
    <p>{{sw2}}</p>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sw1: 0,
      sw2: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    value: () => {
      return Number(this.sw1) + Number(this.sw2)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It was supposed that `<p>{{value}}</p>` shows the computed ( sw1 + sw2 ) value, however it always shows `NaN` in spite of `<p>{{sw1}}</p>` and `<p>{{sw2}}<>/p>` were changed correctly when the status of switches are changed.

Why does `computed:` always return `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use arrow function. Please, do a test and check what is `this` in your code.

Check this

```
computed: {
  value: function () {
    return Number(this.sw1) + Number(this.sw2)
  }
}
```

Vue binding application instance to this function under the hood. It isn't possible for arrow functions.